# Text direction in XWPFTable

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xwpf

How to rotate text using Apache POI in XWPFTable to 90 degrees?

[So it will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6sFx.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

The text direction settings are not implemented into `XWPFTableCell` until now. But using [getCTTc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#getCTTc()) we can get the underlaying [CTTc](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTTc.java) object. And from this we can set [addNewTcPr()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTTcPr.java#CTTcPr), [addNewTextDirection()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTTextDirection.java#CTTextDirection).

For using `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTextDirection` this example needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` as mentioned in the [FAQ-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTextDirection;

public class CreateWordTableTextVertical {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(1,3);
  for (int r = 0; r < 1; r++) {
   for (int c = 0 ; c < 3; c++) {
    XWPFTableCell tableCell = table.getRow(r).getCell(c);
    tableCell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTextDirection().setVal(STTextDirection.BT_LR);
    paragraph = tableCell.getParagraphArray(0);
    run = paragraph.createRun();  
    run.setText("text");
   }
  }

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTableTextVertical.docx"));
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to set the various ENUM alighments form apache poi liberary.  STJc.Enum supports various kind of alignments.

```
public void setTableAlignment(XWPFTable table, STJc.Enum justification) {
    CTTblPr tblPr = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr();
    CTJc jc = (tblPr.isSetJc() ? tblPr.getJc() : tblPr.addNewJc());
    jc.setVal(justification);
}
```