# how to rotate text in XWPFTableCell in apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi

[image]

How to rotate text in XWPFTableCell in apache POI，like the example result in picture, can someone give me some demo, thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010096/text-direction-in-xwpftable/43013702#43013702

Comment: But I found row height does not update automatically to the vertical text length, then the text is not completely showed. Can you give some advice?

Comment: Yes, row height does not update automatically to the vertical text length in some cases. But this is not something what `Word`  has a setting for. So even using the `Word` GUI you could not set this automatism. What about using [XWPFTableRow.setHeight](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableRow.html#setHeight(int))?